# Replace floating numbers in math equation with letter variables

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace all the floating numbers from a mathematical expression with letters using regular expressions. This is what I've tried:

```
Regex rx = new Regex("[-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+");
string expression = "((-30+5.2)*(2+7))-((-3.1*2.5)-9.12)";
char letter = 'a';
while (rx.IsMatch(expression))
{
    expression = rx.Replace(expression , letter.ToString(), 1);
    letter++;
}
```

The problem is that if I have for example `(5-2)+3` it will replace it to: `(ab)+c`

So it gets the -2 as a number but I don't want that.

I am not experienced with Regex but I think I need something like this:

Check for '-', if there is a one, check if there is a number or right parenthesis before it. If there is **NOT** then save the '-'.
After that check for **digits** + **dot** + **digits**

My above Regex also works with values like: **.2 .3 .4** but I don't need that, it should be explicit: **0.2 0.3 0.4**

Comment: It sounds like you need an expression parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggested logic, you may consider

```
(?:(?<![)0-9])-)?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3C!%5B%290-9%5D%29-%29%3F%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F&i=%28%28-30%2B5.2%29*%282%2B7%29%29-%28%28-3.1*2.5%29-9.12%29%0D%0A%28%28-30%2B5.2%29*%282%2B7%29%29-%28%28-3.1*2.5%29-9.12-3%29).

**Regex details**

- `(?:(?<![)0-9])-)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `(?<![)0-9])` - a place in string that is not immediately preceded with a `)` or digit
  - `-` - a minus
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.[0-9]+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of a `.` followed with 1+ digits.

In code, it is better to use a match evaluator (see the [C# demo online](https://ideone.com/7gvJOj)):

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?:(?<![)0-9])-)?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?");
string expression = "((-30+5.2)*(2+7))-((-3.1*2.5)-9.12)";
char letter = (char)96; // char before a in ASCII table
string result = rx.Replace(expression, m => 
    {
        letter++;       // char is incremented
        return letter.ToString();
    }
);
Console.WriteLine(result); // => ((a+b)*(c+d))-((e*f)-g)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed and the explanation helps me understand how it works